# Sending Ether from an account in Node1 to another an account in Node2, both nodes are running in Same network

Tags: ether, nodes

[RESOLVED]I am trying to send ether from Account1 in Node1 to Account1 in Node2, both Node1 and Node2 are running under same network ID. I am able to send ether between accounts in same node but not between different accounts in different nodes. Error is "No key for given address or file".

Comment: Perhaps your nodes aren't communicating? Accounts aren't 'hosted' on any one node, so the only reason you'd see this is if your nodes are partitioned.

Comment: I am able to admin.addPeer(nodeUrl) and I could see that net.peerCount is 1 on both nodes which are under same networkID.

Comment: are you mining?

Comment: Can you ping from one node to the other? If either node is using a firewall, are you forwarding ports TCP/UDP 30303?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running 2 different nodes and it works on 1 node but not on the other, I'm guessing that you don't have a miner running.

Make sure you are mining on that network, otherwise the nodes won't be able to verify transactions with each other.

On the production network other people are mining for you, but on your own test network you have to supply your own mining cycles.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in my comment to the question you must mine. 
Note that not every node has to mine but at least one of the nodes must. The passive nodes will simply sync the newly mined blocks.

Comment: Since I gave the right solution before anybody else I hope to get the reward  :-)